# Error line11 ! Text line contains an invalid character

Tags: errors

I have come to this problem that I can not figure out the solution.

Error line11 ! Text line contains an invalid character

These are lines 1 to 16 do not see any invalid character

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside,final]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage[french,spanish,english]{babel}  
%\usepackage[T1]{fontec}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}               
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,latexsym}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[page]{appendix}
\usepackage{afterpage,caption}      
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{booktabs,longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx,color}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome, are you later inputting any files? The reason is more likely in line 11 of one of those files.

Comment: Dear  @Johannes_B, Thanks for your quick response. Reading some other sources I have found that the problem is that the .aux file is corrupted and not replaced in compilation. I deleted all files .log .aux .dvi, etc., and it worked. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The following file generates all byte positions with invalid category code setting in vanilla LaTeX:

```
\makeatletter
\count@=0
\@whilenum\count@<256\do{%
  \ifnum\catcode\count@=15 %
    \immediate\write16{Invalid character position: \the\count@}%
  \fi
  \advance\count@\@ne
}
\@@end
```

Result:

```
Invalid character position: 0
Invalid character position: 1
Invalid character position: 2
Invalid character position: 3
Invalid character position: 4
Invalid character position: 5
Invalid character position: 6
Invalid character position: 7
Invalid character position: 8
Invalid character position: 11
Invalid character position: 14
Invalid character position: 15
Invalid character position: 16
Invalid character position: 17
Invalid character position: 18
Invalid character position: 19
Invalid character position: 20
Invalid character position: 21
Invalid character position: 22
Invalid character position: 23
Invalid character position: 24
Invalid character position: 25
Invalid character position: 26
Invalid character position: 27
Invalid character position: 28
Invalid character position: 29
Invalid character position: 30
Invalid character position: 31
Invalid character position: 127
```

An invalid character error message can be analyzed the following way:

1. Identification of the input file. This can be done by a careful analysis of the log file/output. TeX prints the file names inside parentheses and the closing parentheses means, the file is read and closed.

   TeX compiler options can also help, e.g. `-file-line-error` (TeX Live) or `--c-style-errors` (MiKTeX).
2. The error message already contains the line number.
3. Then the file can be inspected in a hex viewer/editor. There the error line can be looked for unusual/unexpected characters (for example with character codes shown above). A text viewer/editor is often not a good choice, because it might suppress some character codes (control characters, zero byte, invisible characters, ...).

Comment: Holy cow. I wonder if something like this exists in a utility package somewhere. If it doesn't, it certainly should!